# How to detect if user press back/forword arrow of browser in JS/Jquery for none SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I have only 2 routes

```
/
```

and

```
/about
```

when I am on URL

```
localhost:8080 -> it renders my home page
localhost:8080/about -> it renders about page
```

If user open home page and click on about button and go to about page , not if user will click back button of browser I want just alert "user click on browsers button"

I have tried many internet solution but none of that works
tried this but doest not worked .

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
  alert("You are going to back page. Can work that?");
});
```

Comment: Can you use the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)?

Comment: Please clarify when, and for what purpose, you wish to alert the user with a custom message that they have clicked the back button. Note you may not be able to prevent the back operation from taking place, and may not be able to replace browsers' messsage to the effect that "Are you sure you wish to leave this page?" with any kind of custom message. Sadly more liberal permissions have been abused in the past.

Comment: @traktor just redirect to my error page if user click on back button

Answer (score 0):

you can use the url comparison.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Store the initial URL when the page loads
    var initialUrl = window.location.href;

    // Listen for beforeunload event
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        // Compare the current URL with the initial URL
        if (window.location.href !== initialUrl) {
            // Display alert if the user is navigating away
            return 'You are going to a different page. Are you sure you want to leave?';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: page web site is not single page so each time its reload so initial URL and location.href is always same

Comment: When clicking on about page, store any variable value with the initial url

Answer (score 0):

`popstate` is designed for a SPA, IOW: your SPA on page routing will do a `pushstate`..  You won't get a `popstate` from a none SPA app.

Link -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PopStateEvent

Note: A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document.

Notice the bit that says -> `same document`, IOW: if your navigating to about without using pushstate, then it's not the same document.

A SPA works like this ->

1. pushstate using new URL
2. load the DOM contents for new URL.

Back button pressed

3. popstate fired, load contents of new URL

So you can use jQuery to do this, often what users do is intercept the `a` tag, use `preventDefault` and do 1,2 above.

Note: beforeunload could be used, but be aware its synchronous and very bad UX, especially using alert.  So if you can get push/popstate working you will find you can create much better UX for the user. eg. like been able to use the new HTML Dialog element -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog